# Home screen is blank, lock screen working

Tags: samsung, 2.3-gingerbread, home-screen

I have a Samsung GT-P1000 (about 5 years back from Samsung shop). Upgraded to Gingerbread about 1 year ago. Two weeks back I rooted with last known config as -

- Firmware 2.3.3
- Baseband P1000DDJP4
- Kernel 2.6.35.7 root@SE-S605 #4
- Gingerbread DDJPA

Two days back, I installed AppManager[aka Uninstall Manager] from EasyAppStudio and this app "took over" the home screen and does not exit the app (but kind of swipes right and displays blank screen). Though I was able to use all other apps through this app. I wanted the main home screen so I uninstalled this app. Again same thing but this time I had no access to regular apps. Though I could use soft and hard buttons shortcuts to pull up apps I knew.

Then I hit hard-boot, it is now back to the original look-and-feel but the home screen problem remains. And the only thing I can do now is to use long press on home to bring Task Manager or pull down the status bar. (Locked screen still works and I can unlock the "blank" home screen.

After a hard reset, all shortcuts and old apps were not available. So I emailed myself with a link to Play Store. Got email notification on the status bar, and accessed email and accessed Google Play Store. Got my apps back but home screen is STILL blank. No wallpaper, no icons, no screen swaps, nothing.

Yes, I can download and run anything I want to. But my home screen is blank. Here are some images for a better understanding of the situation.

- Lock screen

  [image]
- Opening Lock

  [image]
- Blank home screen. Note - the top status bar and lower buttons are functional,

  [image]
- Long press on the home button to bring the task manager

  [image]
- Running apps (any app as long as I can access it by the status bar or task manager).

  [image]

Comment: Just to ask, can you try some third party launcher? And also, you can simply install apps through pc. Open play.google.com and sign in with same account as your phone. Go to app you want to install and install it. It will be automatically downloaded to phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after trying many things, I just installed a 3rd-party launcher such as Nova Launcher and suddenly it seemed to work.

I knew it was a launcher issue since everything else was working fine.
I think if you just try and update your Launcher from Play Store or just install a new launcher, everything will be back to normal.